# Multi-Select Faceting in MySQL how to ignore any constraints on a facet?

Tags: mysql, faceted-search

Let’s say we have 3 facets, Size, Color, and Brand.

```
id | name
---------
1  | Size
2  | Color
3  | Brand
```

Our product_facts table looks like this:

```
product_id | facet_id | value
1          | 1        | Small
2          | 1        | Medium
3          | 1        | Medium
4          | 1        | Large
1          | 2        | Red
2          | 2        | Blue
3          | 2        | Black
4          | 2        | Black
1          | 3        | Nike
2          | 3        | Adidas
3          | 3        | Adidas
4          | 3        | Reebok
```

We want the Color and Brand facets to be multi-select, we want the user to be able to select multiple constraints (values).

Querying our table like this:

```
SELECT pf.facet_id, pf.value, count(pf.product_id) AS c
FROM product_facts pf 
GROUP BY pf.facet_id, pf.value
```

would result in a UI (filters):

```
=== Size ===   === Color ===    === Brand ===
[Small] (1)    [ ] Red (1)      [ ] Nike (1)
[Medium] (2)   [ ] Blue (1)     [ ] Adidas (2)
[Large] (1)    [ ] Black (2)    [ ] Reebok (1)
```

User selects "Black":

```
=== Size ===   === Color ===    === Brand ===
[Small] (0)    [ ] Red (0)      [ ] Nike (0)
[Medium] (1)   [ ] Blue (0)     [ ] Adidas (1)
[Large] (1)    [x] Black (2)    [ ] Reebok (1)

SELECT pf.facet_id, pf.value, count(pf.product_id) AS c
FROM product_facts pf 
JOIN products p ON pf.product_id = p.id 
WHERE p.color = 'Black'
GROUP BY pf.facet_id, pf.value
```

The Size and Brand facets now reflect the fact that we’ve selected Black, and that’s what we wanted. But because we filtered out anything that wasn’t Black, we get back 0 counts for other colors. But we still need the other color information so that the user can select more than one colors.

How to achieve this result?

```
=== Size ===   === Color ===    === Brand ===
[Small] (0)    [ ] Red (1)      [ ] Nike (1)
[Medium] (1)   [ ] Blue (1)     [ ] Adidas (2)
[Large] (1)    [x] Black (2)    [ ] Reebok (1)
```

Comment: Logically a separate count would have to be generated for size.  so add a column and use a case statement/or query within the select to get the count specific for color selected, and one without color specific eliminating the where clause.

Comment: @xQbert i'm not sure i understand your suggestion, i'd appreciate if you could give an example.

Comment: Nevermind... I missread the question.

Answer (score 1):

After some effort, i managed to get the expected results with the following approach:

```
SELECT pf.facet_id, pf.value, count(pf.product_id) AS c
FROM product_facts pf 
JOIN products p ON pf.product_id = p.id 
WHERE ((p.color = 'Black' AND pf.facet_id != 2) OR pf.facet_id = 2)
GROUP BY pf.facet_id, pf.value
```

Exclude the color facet when filtering by color or consider it in any other cases.